# Cryptic Clue - "One who will succeed with melody, we hear" Answer - "Heir"

Tags: crosswords, cryptic-crosswords, crossword-clues

obviously I understand the definition part "One who will succeed". But can someone tell me how the word play part works in this clue?

"with melody, we hear"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Heir" is usually pronounced with a silent H, so sounds like "air".
One meaning of the word air is a melody, such as "air on a g string".
"We hear" is a common idiom in cryptic crossword clues for homophones ie "sounds like".
So "melody, we hear" = "sounds like another word for melody" = "sounds like air" = "heir".